# Maven with Spark, Error message by the Java execution

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I use Eclipse to run my Spark code and use tool Maven in Eclipse to build the dependencies. 
Currently I have the situation, when I have to run my code not from Eclipse platform, but from console (bash). I upload and install Maven local on my machine and was playing with the different simple examples. My Maven folder is in Downloads repository. All standard examples are going very well, I have got a right output. All introductions I have found on [this site](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). 
Now I want also execute a spark code. After I have placed my Java file with the spark code in the directory, where I have other files, and updated pom.xml, I couldn't build my jar file. I have got the next error:

```
user@user-HP-ProBook-6570b:~/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app$ mvn package -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ CTI ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/user/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ CTI ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/user/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.728s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 26 15:18:52 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project CTI: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/user/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app/src/main/java/app/SimpleApp.java:[12,11] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project CTI: Compilation failure
/home/user/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app/src/main/java/app/SimpleApp.java:[12,11] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3


    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/home/user/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app/src/main/java/app/SimpleApp.java:[12,11] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3


    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

How I understand, is everything wrong with my Spark version. I use currently spark 1.4.0 version. I also post my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Prototype</groupId>
  <artifactId>CTI</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Regarding the documentation in the link at the bottom of error message it is not a error of maven, [but something wrong is with plugin.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException)

Comment: You need to set your java compiler versnion, it seems like your maven is trying to use java 1.3

Comment: this is strange, maven usually uses the version of $JAVA_HOME setting and I have Java8 in this case...

Comment: I'm just telling you what your error log says.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found similar topics on se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you error log, you need to set your java compiler version in maven to the corresponding java version you are using (1.7 or 1.8). It seems that your maven is using a old version of Java (1.3)

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

This is the line that gave the error up :

```
spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/apache-maven-3.3.3/my-app/src/main/java/app/SimpleApp.java:[12,11] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```